# position gridlayout inside gridlayout kivy

Tags: python, kivy, grid-layout

I'm trying to position a gridlayout(that contains 4 text input) at the center of another gridlayout(that is the rootwidget- ResgistrationWindow in my case) in kivy.but nothing seems to work.

This is my .kv file and the root widget is a grid layout

```
<RegistrationWindow>
cols:1
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        size: self.size
        pos:self.pos
        source:"emotion.jpg"

GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    size_hint: None,None
    size:root.width,root.height/14
    Label:
        text: "Button 1"
        size_hint_x:0.95
    Button:
        text: "X"
        size_hint_x: 0.05

GridLayout:
    cols:1
    size_hint: None, None
    size:root.width, root.height/2
    TextInput:
        multiline:False
    TextInput:
        multiline:False
    TextInput:
        multiline:False
    TextInput:
        multiline:False
```

And this is my .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


class RegistrationWindow(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


kv = Builder.load_file("emotions.kv")


class RegistrationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RegistrationWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RegistrationApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a matter of indentations. Since you want to add your GridLayouts inside your RegistrationWindow, your .kv file should look more like this:

(You can rearrange the GridLayouts further as you like, or indent a GridLayout even more to put it inside another GridLayout.)

```
<RegistrationWindow>
    cols:1
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos:self.pos
            source:"emotion.jpg"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint: None,None
        size:root.width,root.height/14
        Label:
            text: "Button 1"
            size_hint_x:0.95
        Button:
            text: "X"
            size_hint_x: 0.05

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size_hint: None, None
        size:root.width, root.height/2
        TextInput:
            multiline:False
        TextInput:
            multiline:False
        TextInput:
            multiline:False
        TextInput:
            multiline:False
```

Comment: It was actually indented. I made a mistake while pasting the code. Do you know why it could still be giving me this positioning problem though?? Thanks

Comment: Can you post your error or specify what you want? It seemsto work for me.

Comment: I was trying to position the last gridlayout at the center of the root widget. I got it now though. Thanks a lot

Comment: @aisha lawal I am having the same problem. Since you were able to fix your issue, would you please post your solution?